# How to set raster values from one raster to another without getting error

Tags: r, raster, setvalue

I am trying to create a new raster for a pop dataset in R with the same extent and CRS as NLCD_crop using the following code

```
> pop1 <- raster(vals=values(pop),ext=extent(NLCD_crop),crs=crs(NLCD_crop),
                     nrows=dim(NLCD_crop)[1],ncols=dim(NLCD_crop)[2])
```

However I keep getting the error

```
  Error in setValues(r, vals) : 
      length(values) is not equal to ncell(x), or to 1
```

The details for the population raster are:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 5296, 5296, 28047616  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.0003508841, 0.0003508841  (x, y)
extent     : -115.9, -114.0417, 35.00005, 36.85833  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=aea +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : D:/Baylor University/URBN_LMC/30m_run/Raster_30m/POP/ssp1_20_pop30 
names      : ssp1_20_pop30 
values     : 0, 7820.458  (min, max)
```

The details for the NLCD_crop raster are:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 7871, 6787, 53420477  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent     : -1788075, -1584465, 1481625, 1717755  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=aea +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : D:/Baylor University/URBN_LMC/NLCD/nlcd_cc 
names      : nlcd_cc 
values     : 11, 95  (min, max)
attributes :
       ID  COUNT RED GREEN BLUE                     NLCD_LAND OPACITY CLASS
 from: 11 306366  70   107  159                    Open Water     255    11
  to : 95  29597 108   159  184 Emergent Herbaceuous Wetlands     255    95
```

Any help would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make your example reproducible. You have

```
library(raster)
pop <- raster(nrow=5296, ncol=5296, 
            xmn=-115.9, xmx=-114.0417, ymn=35.00005, ymx=36.85833, 
            crs="+proj=aea +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m")
values(pop) <- 1:ncell(pop)
    
nlcd <- raster(nrow=7871, ncol=6787, 
        xmn=-1788075, xmx=-1584465, ymn=1481625, ymx=1717755,
        crs="+proj=aea +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m")
```

You need to fix `pop`, as the crs is clearly wrong.

```
crs(pop) <- "+proj=longlat"
```

Now you can use projectRaster (it takes a minute or so to run):

```
x <- projectRaster(pop, nlcd)
```